# How to ingest AWS ALB logs in S3 to Loki?

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer, grafana-loki

I'm attempting to ingest AWS ALB logs into Loki but I can't seem to find a smooth way to do this. AWS ALB logs end up in S3 for consumption through Athena or other sources but Loki doesn't have a simple way to ingest S3 logs.

Is there a known way to accomplish this?

Comment: How about using Lambda function? Not the same but this shows the example from CW logs to Loki. https://github.com/ClaudioWaldvogel/cloudwatch-loki-shipper

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work because AWS ALB logs don't end up in cloudwatch..

Comment: But Lambda can access S3, right?

Comment: Sorry if you're looking for things ready to use.

Comment: Ahh it sounds like you're suggesting I take a look at this and fit it to work with Loki?

Comment: @TravelingLex: How did you accomplished it?

Comment: @NaveenKumar, unfortunately I determined that I need to create a service that reads AWS ALB logs in S3 and pushes the logs to Loki. This work has been deprioritized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[lambda-promtail](https://github.com/grafana/loki/tree/main/tools/lambda-promtail) recently gained the ability to ingest ALB logs from S3, in [this merged pull request](https://github.com/grafana/loki/pull/5065). The lambda is triggered by an S3 bucket notification. The repository includes example Terraform and CloudFormation configs for setting it up.